# Please someone explain me how TextView textView; object use in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Sorry if you don't understand my question. I try to explain. So in java we create object like Class object = new Class(); something like that. And then use this object to access class methods and instances like object.method(); something like that. But in android when we access some xml we use TextView textView; and then textView = findViewById(R.id.tvTempText); something like that. So for me confusing part is why not we use something like that TextView textView = new TextView(); and then use object like that textView.findViewById(R.id.tvTempText);

Answer (score 0):

Findviewbyid() has a return type of view so then we r assigning findviewbyid() methods return value to the textview object as textview extends view class.

Comment: ok But why we not instantiate object like TextView textView = new TextView(); How we can use object without instantiate it. For example in above we only declare object TextView textView; but we not instantiate object. so how can we use object without instantiate.

Comment: There is difference between variable nd object and when we use findviewbyid() it's not an object to which we reference it, it's a variable of type view.